# Prefixing Data Annotation Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

The scenario is I have an object I'm using multiple times in a razor form, and I need to prefix the error message data attributes so that they make sense in the validation summary.

Quick example:

```
public class Person 
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is Required")]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "First Name must be 30 characters or less")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class User 
{
    [Required]
    public Person User { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Person NextOfKin { get; set; }
}

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.User.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "First Name" }})

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.NextOfKin.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "First Name" }})
```

If I used the User class in the form, and the FirstName was left empty in multiple locations the error messages would be identical with nothing to distinguish between the two.

What are my best options in this scenario?

**update**: To highlight the need for prefixing multiple ErrorMessage strings.

Thanks.

Comment: You can make viewModel / DTO(Domain transfer object) class.Add User & Person property in side. Then use the viewModel in page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to overwrite the respective validation message in the form using the title attribute client side.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "User First Name is required"} })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName,"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<!-- NextOfKin entry -->
@Html.EditorFor(y => y.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "Next Of Kin First Name is required"} })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(y => y.FirstName,"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: The `title` attribute has nothing to do with mvc validation (nor does the `required` attribute which is ignored)

Comment: How would this handle multiple validation error messages, such as required, length, regex, etc

Comment: I'm also only using ValidationSummary.